# Kotlinx injects view from wrong layout

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a piece of code that checks whether view is visible

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_layout.*

val isOverflowPanelShown: Boolean
   get() = overflow_panel.visibility != View.GONE
```

previous code throws exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView
    at com.company.app.Activity.isOverflowPanelShown(Activity.kt:362)
```

The view is instance of `ScrollView` class, however kotlin thinks its a `FrameLayout`. Calling findViewById() on the same place as error is thrown it correctly returns ScrollView. I found that in **different layout** in the application there is a **`FrameLayout` under same id**.

I am inflating following layout

`activity_layout`

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/overflow_panel"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

In another layout that I use on entirely different place, there is a different view with the same id.

`form_component_main`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overflow_panel" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug. Can you provide some more details about where are `activity_layout` and `form_component_main` located? Maybe, these layouts are in different modules?
Also it would be great if you could reproduce this behaviour in a small sample project.

Comment: I'm experimenting the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No and I havent enountered it since.

Answer (score 2):

Why not give them different ids?

```
overflow_panel_scroll
overflow_panel_frame
```

Or something more descriptive to what they actually do.

**UPDATE:** A little more explanation as this got down voted. IDs should be unique.

The Android documentation says that there can be conflicts if IDs aren't unique: `An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).` (from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Kotlin synthetics are produced by an IntelliJ plugin. Without the IDs being unique, it seems that the plugin cannot currently correctly match the ID to the correct view. It may be expecting unique IDs.

Comment: I could eventually do that, but I rather change as little code as possible, and not introduce another issues. I did not write the application, I am just maintaining it. I thing that having same ids in different layouts is should not cause problems.

Comment: Is form_component_main ever shown on the activity that uses activity_layout?

Comment: It's in a fragment that is deep down in the hierarchy. The framgnet is not inflated from the same layout.

Btw.. Calling findViewById() on the same place as error is thrown it correctly returns ScrollView

Comment: I'm fairly new to synthetics. I'm not sure how the generated R.java and synthetics interact. It might be worth searching for overflow_panel in your R.java (should be in app > build > generated > source > r > ......). It may get multiple versions that findViewById can handle but synthetics can't.

Comment: This is only thing I found in  .....>source>r>debug>packageId>R.java `public static final int overflow_panel=0x7f0b0085;`

Comment: So there must just be one id. This gives the possibility for conflict. The Android documentation says that there can be conflicts: `An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).` (from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) I'm guessing it is a coincidence of how synthetics calculate what they are pointing at versus findViewByID that this error appears for one but not the other.

Comment: Yeah that could be it, I cant find the source code for Kotlin Android Extensions.

Comment: It looks like it is handled by an IntelliJ extension: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/ee50aec7342ab375a105bb318e6501135e859028/plugins/android-extensions/android-extensions-compiler It may be worth asking on the Kotlin forums.

Comment: It looks like it does some kind of caching AndroidExpressionCodegenExtension.kt#L367 but I hardly understand the code. In theory does it mean if kotlin synthetizer caches id from another layout, it could cause my issue.